# VSTS stories and wiki page created or edited email alert?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, alert, user-stories

I am new to **Visual Studio Team Services** *(as well as MS Teams),* and no one on my team seems to know how to do this, nor am I finding any love on Google.

- Alert when a story is created in VSTS
- Alert when a wiki page is created in VSTS
- Alert when a story is edited in VSTS
- Alert when a wiki page is edited in VSTS

*(I am adding those four separately for search purposes)*  **Alert would ideally be an email.**

Ideally it would include **if files are attached** to either story or wiki (but that could be covered by a "last modified date" on the story/wiki itself?) or an existing **file is modified**.

I can't help, but think that *the access level I've been given* is part of the problem (average user as opposed to administrator level). *It may be hidden from me?*

---

**PARTIALLY RESOLVED 2018-03-27 11:30 EST**

**For STORIES, see screenshots below.** *No support for wikis have been found yet.*

1. Gear icon, Project Settings *(wording may vary)*
   [image: Step 1]
2. Notifications, new subscription
   [image: Step 2]
3. Create subscription
   [image: Step 3]

---

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. However, for User Stories, it is more transparent than for Wiki Pages.

First of all, get acquainted with [this generic guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/notifications/manage-personal-notifications?view=tfs-2017) about how to configure notifications in VSTS.

#### Work item notifications

As long as the User Story is just a work item of the specific type, you can configure a work item notification. For instance, when a new work item is created:

[image]

Note: I have a different project template in the screenshot above - there's no User Story work item type, but you should get the idea.

Similar to this, you can configure a "work item is modified" type of notification, tweaking the query parameters according to your needs.

#### Wiki page notifications

There's no specific notification type for wiki page changes, as far as I know. However, internally wiki is just another Git repository. If you navigate to the main Wiki view of your project, and click *More* arrow, you'll see the option to clone the wiki repo, and there you'll find its name, too:

[image]

Thus, you can work around the lack of wiki notification type by tweaking a "commit is pushed" notification:

[image]

Each wiki subpage resides in the folder named by the parent page. Grouping the wiki articles properly, you can at least setup the notifications for a group of pages.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the heads up on the possibility for Wiki.  I will be trying this soon "in my spare time" (insert laughter)  ;)